# Measuring relationships between variables directly (survey)

Tags: experiment-design, survey

I have a question related to how to set up my survey to collect meaningful data.

I have several hypotheses that look like "A effects B", say "using CrossValidated increases team productivity". I can collect data by doing a survey with participants who (hypothetically) observe these real-world effects in practice.

Now, my initial thought was to look at A and B as variables, measure them with survey questions, and continue with the usual analysis to see if there is a correlation.

However, I would much prefer to not measure A nor B, but ask the survey participants directly "Does using CrossValidated increase your team's productivity?". While this will obviously get subjective results it feels much better fitting. Especially as I think that "CrossValidated usage" or "team productivity" are in my case not objectively measurable anyway.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Are there any downsides I am not seeing?

*By the way, this is my first question, let me know if I can help to improve it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have identified most of the important issues.  As you stated, direct measures of "CrossValidated usage" or "team productivity" may be difficult.

Perhaps an even deeper issue is this:  even if you could measure thing A and thing B directly, it is a big step to say whether thing A *causes* thing B.  To get at causation without some crazy assumptions, you pretty much need to have randomized assignment of the treatment (CrossValidated usage).

Since you don't seem to be in a position to do random assignment, I recommend doing as you have suggested and directly asking respondents about whether they believe CrossValidated Usage increases productivity.

I would consider some other versions of your question as well, such as "*how much* does CrossValidated Usage increase (or decrease) your productivity?"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the approach of asking these kind of questions have a name or is it simply "asking the right questions"?

The reason I am asking is that the examples in the literature that I have found all go the route of measuring A and B, and I have yet to find an example where the relationship between those variables itself is "measured". That's why I was assuming that I am either overlooking important issues, or looking in the wrong spot.

Comment: To answer my own follow-up question, I found this is often simply called asking "causal questions".  
  
  I found related issues such as social desirability bias, problems associated with leading questions, and researches considering people to be generally ignorant about the causal reality. (Some of these issues may apply in my case, so I will have to try to avoid them by designing good questions.)